# How to use apache avro GenericRecord for dynamic data?

Tags: java, c++, avro

I want to use Apache Avro to serialize my data, my client is written in C++, and my server is written in Java.

1. My server java code looks like this:

   ```
   Schema scm = new Schema.Parser().parse("....shcema String.....");
   ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(record.array());
   Decoder coder = new DecoderFactory().directBinaryDecoder(inputStream, null);
   GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord> reDatumReader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(scm);
   try {
       GenericRecord result = (GenericRecord)reDatumReader.read(null, coder);
               //here! the result "name", "num_groups" is empty!
       System.out.println(result.get("name")+"   "+result.get("num_groups"));
   } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
2. And my client code:

   ```
   std::string schemaDescript ="....shcema String.....";

   std::stringstream rsStream(schemaDescript);
   avro::ValidSchema rSchema;
   avro::compileJsonSchema(rsStream, rSchema);
   avro::EncoderPtr encoder = avro::binaryEncoder();
   std::auto_ptr<avro::OutputStream> oStream = avro::memoryOutputStream();
   encoder->init(*oStream);   
   avro::GenericDatum rData(rSchema);
   avro::GenericRecord sReord = rData.value<avro::GenericRecord>();
   sReord.setFieldAt(0, avro::GenericDatum("i am nice"));
   sReord.setFieldAt(1, avro::GenericDatum(1));
   sReord.setFieldAt(2, avro::GenericDatum(12));
   sReord.setFieldAt(3, avro::GenericDatum(13));

   avro::GenericWriter gwriter(rSchema, encoder);
   gwriter.write(rData);
   oStream->flush();

   std::auto_ptr<avro::InputStream> inSt = avro::memoryInputStream(*oStream);
   avro::StreamReader instReader(*inSt);

   size_t outputLen = oStream->byteCount();
   uint8_t* theByteData = new uint8_t[outputLen];
   instReader.hasMore();
   instReader.readBytes(theByteData, outputLen);
   ```

I send the `theByteData` to the server, the code works (no exception), but the result is empty, can anyone tell me what's wrong?

And why in Java we get value with key: `result.get("name")`; but in C++ we get value with index: `record.fieldAt(0).value<string>()`. If I can't get value with the string key, how to match the index to string key?

Comment: Thanks to dominikh, edited my question.

Comment: 3 years later, any news ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem this morning and i found a solution in the Avro Test Cpp file("DataFileTests.cc") with the "testWriteGeneric" function.

For example:

My Schema file(cpx.json):

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "cpx",
  "fields" : [
  {"name": "re", "type": "double"},
  {"name": "im", "type" : "int"}
  ]
 }
```

My Cpp file:

```
typedef std::pair<avro::ValidSchema, avro::GenericDatum> Pair;

int main(int ac, char **av)
{

    // encode
    std::ifstream ifs(cpx.json);
    avro::ValidSchema schema;
    avro::compileJsonSchema(ifs, schema);

    // I create a pair of validSchema and GenericDatum
    Pair p(schema, avro::GenericDatum());

    avro::GenericDatum &Data = p.second;
    Data = avro::GenericDatum(schema);
    avro::GenericRecord &sReord = Data.value<avro::GenericRecord>();

    // I set my values
    sReord.setFieldAt(sReord.fieldIndex("re"), avro::GenericDatum(42.5));
    sReord.setFieldAt(sReord.fieldIndex("im"), avro::GenericDatum(24));


    // I create a DataFileWriter and i write my pair of ValidSchema and GenericValue
    avro::DataFileWriter<Pair> dataFileWriter("test.bin", schema);
    dataFileWriter.write(p);
    dataFileWriter.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with the client code in following statements

```
avro::GenericRecord sReord = rData.value<avro::GenericRecord>();
sReord.setFieldAt(0, avro::GenericDatum("i am nice"));
```

Second statement will result into call to `avro::GenericDatum(bool)` and not `GenericDatum(const std::string&)` as intended.
Due to this the string field remains empty and hence when you will try to read it, empty string will be returned. So, replacing above statement with following should work

```
std::string s("i am nice");
sReord.setFieldAt(0, avro::GenericDatum(s));
```

In first statement, sRecord should be declared as a reference as that's what is returned by rData.value(). Not taking as reference just replaces it with a new copy and thus any value written in it doesn't actually gets written in underlying stream. So, it should be

```
avro::GenericRecord& sReord = rData.value<avro::GenericRecord>();
```

Also, you don't need GenericWriter and can write using Encoder object itself as

```
avro::encode(*encoder, rData);
```